# Проблемы с Select (BSD сокеты)

Tags: c, сокет, bsd

Я хочу написать простой клиент который будет посылать запрос серверу и получать от него данные. Данные будут приходить постепенно поэтому я в цикле написал такую штуку:

```
    //ОСНОВНОЙ ЦИКЛ
while (TRUE) {/**/
    // проверяем готов ли таргет принимать данные или отправлять данные
    if (select(s + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, 0) == -1) {
        perror("select");
        break;
    }   
    // отправляем посылку
    if (FD_ISSET(s, &write_fds)) {
        printf("write_fds\n");
        if (send(s, &outData, sizeof(SendPack), 0) == -1) {
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
        // дабы не попасть сюда второй раз
        FD_ZERO(&write_fds);
    }
    // принимаем посылку
    if (FD_ISSET(s, &read_fds)) {
        printf("read_fds\n");
        // считываем данные
        if ((numbytes = recv(s, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        // печатаем пришедшие данные
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("numbytes: %d \n", numbytes);
        printf("received string: %s \n", buf);
    }// конец чтения
}
```

Но как только данные отправлены, я не попадаю в условие чтения  **if (FD_ISSET(s, &read_fds))**, и при **Select** получаю ошибку и выхожу.  При всем при этом если убрать условие и написать так:

```
// отправляем посылку
    if (FD_ISSET(s, &write_fds)) {
        printf("write_fds\n");
        if (send(s, &outData, sizeof(SendPack), 0) == -1) {
            perror("send");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    // принимаем посылку
    if (FD_ISSET(s, &read_fds)) {
        printf("read_fds\n");
        // считываем данные
        if ((numbytes = recv(s, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0)) == -1) {
            perror("recv");
            exit(1);
        }
        // печатаем пришедшие данные
        buf[numbytes] = '\0';
        printf("numbytes: %d \n", numbytes);
        printf("received string: %s \n", buf);
    }// конец чтения
```

все исправно работает.

Объясните пожалуйста как читать в цикле с использованием select? Сокет ставил в неблокирующий режим - не помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обратите внимание на описание `RETURN VALUE`   в [man select](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html) -- *"On success, select() and pselect() return the* ***number of file
       descriptors*** *contained in the three returned descriptor sets (that is,
       the total number of bits* ***that are set*** *in readfds, writefds,
       exceptfds)"*.

Таким образом,если в вашем алгоритме нет серьезных противопоказаний к обработке *всех* произошедших событий друг за другом, в общем случае цикл может выглядеть примерно так:

```
  ... // тут у вас появляется s
  while (1) {
    FD_ZERO(&read_fds);  set_all_read_fds(&read_fds, s);
    FD_ZERO(&write_fds); set_all_write_fds(&write_fds, s);
    // очевидно, что номера интересующих вас дескрипторов, 
    // которые устанавливются внутри set_all_read_fds() и set_all_write_fds() 
    // где-то должны храниться

    int n;
    if ((n = select(s + 1, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, 0)) > 0) {
      for (int fd = 0; n && fd < s + 1; fd++) {
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &read_fds))
          do_read(fd), n--;
        if (FD_ISSET(fd, &write_fds))
          do_write(fd), n--;
      }
    } else if (!n) 
      do_unexpected_timeout(); // unexpected, поскольку таймаут тут не задан
    else
      do_select_error_action();
  }
```

Comment: уточню прямым текстом, что конкретная ошибка в том, что все `fd set`'ы должны устанавливаться заново перед каждым вызовом `select ()` т.к. оный изменяет входные данные.